# Stop an ArrayList from gathering multiple data instead of one in Excel, Apache POI

Tags: java, apache, arraylist, import-from-excel

I'm importing an Excel file and trying to gather data in the cells in one single column, like this:

[image: image 1]

When I attempt to do so, somehow, with the code down below, I get the following results:

[image: image 2]

Is there a way that I could possibly just get [Teacher's name, HELLO, as, asd]?

```
HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(file);
HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
int temp = sheet.getPhysicalNumberOfRows();
int numberoftickets = temp - 1;

List < String > a = new ArrayList < String > ();
for (Row row: sheet) {
    Cell c = row.getCell(0);
    if (c.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING) {
        a.add(c.getStringCellValue());
    }

String[] simpleArray = a.toArray(new String[a.size()]);
String aa = Arrays.toString(simpleArray);
StringTokenizer t = new StringTokenizer(aa, ",");

System.out.println(a);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are printing out the results *inside* your for loop so it prints once per row.

Instead, print the array list outside of the for loop (after the `}` that ends the for loop.

```
for (Row row: sheet) {
    Cell c = row.getCell(0);
    if (c.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING) {
        a.add(c.getStringCellValue());
    }
} // this brace closes the for loop

//put your print code and tokenize code here
```

Comment: I'm already printing after the Iteration. I don't know why it is printing more than once.

Answer (score 0):

Try Printing Result after `Iteration`

```
for(Row row: sheet){
  // Do Whatever you want to do  
}
System.out.println(a);
```

Comment: I'm already printing after the Iteration. I don't know why it is printing more than once.